# Java Character Switch

Tags: java, string

What's a really easy way to switch characters around in Java? Say I have the following:

```
String testString = "Hello World.";

// I know this doesn't work
testString = testString.replace('o', 'e');
```

I want to switch the 'e' with 'o' and I know this won't work... Please let me know what i need to do

Comment: Do you want it to work on all characters in the string or only on the first occurrence?

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work? If doesn't do what you want, what *does* it do?

Comment: How about testString.replace("o", "e"); ?

Comment: I tested it and it makes it say "Hollo World". I need it to say "Holle Werld". So basically switch them around in every occurence. is this possible?

Comment: You can build your own method that does that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
 String testString = "Hello World.";
 String replacedString = testString.replaceAll("o", "~")
                                   .replaceAll("e","o")
                                   .replaceAll("~","e");
```

Okay as long as your string doesn't have a ~

Comment: +1 for `.replaceAll()` chaining. One might try to find some more exotic character, but `~` is good for example purposes.

Comment: Why does it tell me that "The method replaceAll(String, String) in the type String is not applicable for the arguments (char, char)"?

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to use a temp character:

```
testString = testString.replace('o', '@');
testString = testString.replace('e', 'o');
testString = testString.replace('@', 'e');
```

This may or may not be ideal, depending on the range of possible characters in the string, the length and how many times it needs to be executed. But for the example string it does work :-)

Comment: I am not the one who downvoted you, but maybe it was because replaceAll does not take a character, it takes a String.

Comment: @proflux, good catch, thanks :-) Originally it was `replace`, then I changed it but didn't check the parameters. Fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

You can build your own method that does that.

```
String SwitchCharOcurrences(String original, char x, char y) {
    char[] cArray = original.toCharArray();
    for(int i = 0; i < cArray.length; i++) {
        if(cArray[i] == x) {
            cArray[i] = y;
        } else if(cArray[i] == y) {
            cArray[i] = x;
        }
    }
    String result = new String (cArray);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Not sure if you have to NULL terminate the String when you send a Char Array as the parameter in the constructor.

Comment: In c, the purpose of a NULL terminator in a char array is to indicate the end of the string. In java all arrays have a length property that serves the same purpose. So we don't need NULL terminators in java.

Answer (score 0):

Not with a single method call.

```
StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
for(char c : testString.toCharArray()) // CharSequence should really be usable in such a loop
{
   switch(c) {
      case 'e': c = 'o'; break;
      case 'o': c = 'e'; break;
   }
    buf.append(c);
}
testString = buf.toString();
```

The canonical version would be this:

```
StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();

for(int i = 0; i <testString.length(); i++)
{
   char c = testString.charAt(i);
   switch(c) {
      case 'e': c = 'o'; break;
      case 'o': c = 'e'; break;
   }
    buf.append(c);
}
testString = buf.toString();
```

Could someone benchmark those two versions for different String lengths?

Comment: `toCharArray()` creates new array and copies the string AFAIR. It's better to use `charAt()`.

Comment: @Alex: Please measure it ... I mainly used `toCharArray` because it is easier to use in this for loop, but it also saves multiple individual `charAt` calls.

Comment: @Paulo, that's not my -1 ) Agreed that is should be measured but that's microoptimization anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the string and build the replacement string by examining each character. Something like this:

```
String testString = "Hello World.";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i=0, length=testString.length(); i<length; i++) {
    char ch = testString.charAt(i);
    switch (ch) {
          case 'e':
              sb.append('o');
              break;
          case 'o':
              sb.append('e');
              break;
          default:
              sb.append(ch);
    }
}
String replacedString = sb.toString();
```

If you want to swap capital letters too you can do this:

```
String testString = "Hello World.";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i=0, length=testString.length(); i<length; i++) {
    char ch = testString.charAt(i);
    switch (ch) {
          case 'e':
              sb.append('o');
              break;
          case 'E':
              sb.append('O');
              break;
          case 'o':
              sb.append('e');
              break;
          case 'O':
              sb.append('E');
              break;
          default:
              sb.append(ch);
    }
}
String replacedString = sb.toString();
```

But the switch statement is starting to get a bit long and messy. If you needed to add much more to it, it might get out of hand. A little refactoring might lead to this:

```
String testString = "Hello World.";

Map<Character,Character> replacementMap = new HashMap<Character,Character>();
replacementMap.put('e', 'o');
replacementMap.put('o', 'e');
replacementMap.put('E', 'O');
replacementMap.put('O', 'E');

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i=0, length=testString.length(); i<length; i++) {
    char ch = testString.charAt(i);
    Character replacement = replacementMap.get(ch);
    sb.append(replacement != null ? replacement : ch);
}
String replacedString = sb.toString();
```

Answer (score -1):

This may be not optimal, but relatively easy ;)

```
String testString = "Hello World.";

testString = testString.replace('o', '\u0001');
testString = testString.replace('e', 'o');
testString = testString.replace('\u0001', 'e');
```

The idea is to take a character that you are sure is not used in string and use it as temporary replace.